# Characteristics of 'loan word root + る' verbs

Tags: verbs, morphology

This question follows on from these others:

- [What are the principles behind turning foreign language words into verbs?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24351/what-are-the-principles-behind-turning-foreign-language-words-into-verbse-g-%E3%82%B0)
- [Why are there very few non-する gairaigo verbs in Japanese?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65305/why-are-there-very-few-non-%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-gairaigo-verbs-in-japanese/65325#65325)
- [Are there words which consist of katakana and hiragana letters together?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15199/are-there-words-which-consist-of-katakana-and-hiragana-letters-together)
- [Are there nouns that can function as another part of speech?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12948/are-there-nouns-that-can-function-as-another-part-of-speech/12949#12949)

I am trying to catalog the specific verb type `loan word root + る` in terms of meaning, inflection patterns, pitch-accent characteristics, etc. Hopefully this will identify any clear patterns and/or irregularities. So far, I have come up with the following list (see below).

Please point out any any errors you see - I will amend and update the list accordingly.
Also, feel free to add any more that you know.

[image: ‘loan word + る’ verbs]

Comment: - [若者ことばの「体言＋る」動詞](https://osaka-kyoiku.ac.jp/_file/gakusei/kikaku/gakudayori/166/campus_kotoba.pdf)
- [外来語由来の動詞（例：ググる）](https://www.lancers.jp/work/detail/1642340)

Comment: thanks. there are some very interesting ones there in both links. i will include the 外来語 words and edit the list.

Comment: サボる is from sabotage and is used in a much wider range than just "cut class".

Comment: Of course. I just included a basic meaning keyword. But thanks :)

Comment: I observe that 長音 is usually cut out even if the original spelling contains it.

Comment: This is an interesting undertaking, but is it really a question?

Comment: IMO ハモる is more like “to be in sync”. E.g. when two people accidentally say the same thing simultaneously: 「あ、ハモった！」

Comment: Saw シャワる a few minutes ago on Twitter: https://twitter.com/syokumutaiman/status/1195392120850243585

Comment: シャワる is a new one for me. Thanks ! I'll update the list.

Comment: One more: ジェラる (to be jealous)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went on a dictionary dive through Daijirin. Here are some additional ones:

- ガスる - (from "gas") to get foggy (e.g. of a mountain in the distance) - [2]
- サチる - to saturate - [2]
- サマる - to summarize - [2]
- タクる - to take a taxi - [2]
- タピる - to drink a tapioca/boba drink - [2]
- ダビる - to dub with audio - [2]
- ダフる - to duff (British golf slang for hitting the ground behind the ball, thus reducing the power of the shot) - [2]
- チキる - to act chicken / act weak or scared - [2]
- デコる - to decorate gaudishly - [2]
- デモる - to demonstrate (e.g. as part of a rights movement) - [2]
- ディスる - to diss (i.e. to speak disrespectfully about / insult someone) - [2]
- ネガる - to become negative - [2]
- ネグる - to neglect to do / to ignore - [2]
- ネゴる - to negotiate - [2]
- バトる - to fight / to battle - [2]
- パニクる - to panic - [3]
- パロる - to parody - [2]
- ヒスる - to have a fit of hysterics - [2]
- ビニる - to go to the convenience store - [2]
- ラグる - to lag - [2]
- リヌる - (from "renew") to renovate a web page - [2]
- リムる - (from "remove") to unfollow online - [2]
- レボる - (from "revolution") to reform one's own actions and habits - [2]
- ロム(ROM)る - (from "ROM" (Read-Only Member), i.e. a member who reads but doesn't post) to read online posts without posting anything oneself (often used in the sense of "shut up", e.g. ロムれ) - [2?]

There are probably a lot more that don't make it into the dictionaries. オナる comes to mind. If there's a word that's popular and has a two-syllable abbreviation, it's probably likely that someone, somewhere has attached る to it. As for the pitch accent, all of these fit the pattern described so far (downstep directly before る).

Comment: English analog for ロムる seems to be “to lurk”.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky Yeah, pretty much. It differs in the modalities in which it gets used, though. Ex from the internet 「知らないくせに適当なこと書くなよ。黙ってROMってろよ」.
This also appears to have become a meme, albeit a dead one: 「半年ROMれ」[article](https://numan.tokyo/words/4Pwr0).
To contrast, in English it'd be very weird if you told someone "shut up and lurk".

Answer (score 2):

Some general observations of the patterns visible so far.

- The pitch accent is consistent, with a downstep just before the last mora.
- A subset of these terms re-analyze the final //l// in English as verb-ending る:

  - ググる
  - ダブる
  - トラブる
- ハモる is an almost-pun, or a kind of missing apophone for the はまる・はめる verb pair "to fit", considering that, when harmonizing, the various sounds must fit together nicely.
- Two end in バる, a common enough suffixing element when spelled 張る.
- *(Almost certainly accidental resemblance):* Several of these almost come across as rare or dialectal English rendered in katakana -- the [*-le* suffix](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-le#Etymology_1) is a common frequentative element in English.  I found that [*buzzle*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/buzzle) does seem to be an actual word, and although I cannot find evidence of *buggle* other than [the band name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Buggles), it almost works as a native English term.
- A couple others appear to play on other terms or other forms that end in リ (ファボリ[ート], メモリ) and re-analyze that as the 連用形, thus back-constructing the plain form of the verb ending in る.
- One seems to just omit an otherwise-doubled mid-word す (ミスする → ミスる), with the attendant change of the る from the vanishing サ変 ending to 五段.  バズる could be viewed as a similar instance.

There's lots of fun word play going on with these.  I'm curious if an expanded list might find additional examples of the above patterns.

Comment: Interesting comments there. I'm not sure about the le-suffix - I had assumed these were just direct verbalization of a noun which was already in Japanese. The nouns バグ (bug) and バズ (buzz) already existed as far as I know. Simply adding the る made them verbs ('to bug', 'to buzz').I thought the same might be true for メモ ('a memo') and ミス ('a miss') which are also standard nouns in Japanese. So again, just adding the る to a basic noun might be the pattern of verbalization ('to memo').  What do you think?

Comment: @kandyman, re: the _-le_ suffix, I'd meant to rework the intro comment -- I'm 95+% sure that's coincidence.  I just thought it was interesting enough to comment on, especially when I discovered the existence of _buzzle_.  :)  Re: メモ, yes, it's addition of る.  The wordplay and word-shape association with メモリ is interesting, and may have been an influencing factor.  Re: ミスる, I do think that this represents a shift from earlier ミスする.

Answer (score 1):

Not coming from loan words, but a related  category of such verbs come from onomatopoeia, especially those having the ABABする pattern. For example:

- ボコボコ(する) → ボコる (to beat the hell out of)
- ニコニコ(する) → ニコる (to smile; only seen on  ニコニコ動画 so far)
- パコパコ(する) → パコる (to have sex)
- ドキドキ(する) → ドキった (have been surprised)

The last one could be actually coming directly from ドキっと(した); I don’t think I’ve ever seen the infinitive form ドキる.

Comment: Note that for ボコボコ it'd normally be ボコボコ"に"する and not ボコボコする, so it's interesting that it becomes ボコる. It would appear that these る words only capture a restricted sense of their parent words.