# Why った after a noun デコった?

Tags: abbreviations, past

Is it just an abbreviation for だった? Any nuance or just laziness?

[image]

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/66495/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

デコった is the past tense of デコる, a slangy way to say "to decorate."

Comment: Oooh, the dictionary put it really far in the list so I didn't see it, I should've guessed, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think it's shortened usage of "デコりやがった" or more clearly "～しやがった(の(は))", which is strong way of saying "した" / "したの(は)", in this case the complete sentence will be "(俺の)右腕をデコレーションしたのピンクだな!?".

Comment: As far as grammar goes, there is no やがる in the original sentence.

Comment: @naruto I... didn't wrote any やがる in my answer? where did you find it?

Comment: Ah, you meant デコりやがった → やがる? sorry, I just added that for clarity. Sorry if it's confusing.